# PHP Restriction when using image tracking

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good day everyone!

Well here's the thing;
One .htaccess file, mod rewrite, to redirect imagename.png (non existing file) to tracker.php (real file). So when a user is looking at site.com/hello.png the user is actuall looking at /hello.php which gather information and stores it.

**tracker.php**

```
<?php
$date = date('d-m-Y');
$time = date('H:i:s');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ref = @$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo gzinflate(base64_decode('6wzwc+flkuJiYGDg9fRwCQLSjCDMwQQkJ5QH3wNSbCVBfsEMYJC3jH0ikOLxdHEMqZiTnJCQAOSxMDB+E7cIBcl7uvq5rHNKaAIA'));

$myFile = "tr.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
fwrite($fh, $myFile = $time ." | ". $date . " | " .$ip. " | " .$ref. " | \r\n\r\n");
fclose($fh);
?>
```

I am using it on my site to track visitors. Everything works fine, I could gather information about ip, webbrowser, ref-link etc.

But my question is, what are the restriction when doing this? I have been experimenting a long time and it seems like I could only use plain php (not *echo "some other language"*).
I can not redirect or echo text. Loops, if/else, variables etc is working.
If I tries to redirect I could see that the page is attempting to connect to e.g. google but just for a second so there are no actual redirects.

tl;dr
What are the restriction in code when using a php file as an image?

Comment: There are no restrictions in terms of the kind of code you can write - you can do whatever you like, server-side (connect to databases, create an image dynamically, access an API, etc). On the client, you can add headers and set cookies, but yes, you can't write ordinary text - that would corrupt your image, so there would be no point. From what you say, it seems you can redirect an image request using Apache directives, so you should be able to do that in PHP too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any restrictions. 
Your php code is executed and runs.

What you display doesn't restrict php.

You mentioned a redirect there. You're loading an image in a html page (generated by php or not, doesn't matter). The html page received it's headers from the server, and your php generated image also received it's headers (content-type image). Here is where the redirect would be.
There's no reason why your html page will ever redirect using a php headers function on your image.

If you load the php generated image directly in your browser, I think you'll be able to redirect the user (directly, without displaying the image), but as an image in a html page, it's not possible to affect the rest of the page, unless you use javascript.